# want to addd a column in ofMessageArchive table of Monitoring Service plugin of openfire

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, real-time-updates

we are developing a real time application for that we are using openfire framework  and for message archiving we had installed monitoring services and open archive it work great and messages archived successfully

but not according to are requirement we want to distinguish between messages from a group 
so we want to add anather column in ofMessageArchive  but after adding anther column it stops adding messages in that

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we talking about the "ofmessagearchive" table in the openfire DB. If so, you could easy distinguish if the message was from one to one or a group chat message by the JID.

Take the "toJID" column and look if the entry contains "conference" (If you group chat service is named "conference", thats the default value) then is the message a Group message, otherwise it is one to one message.

Example:

**Group message** -> open_chat@conference.xmpp-domain

**Normal message** -> username@xmpp-domain

Comment: u got it right we are talking about ofmessagearchive but in my requirement there is only one to one chating and each chating is related to particular order for that i want to add a orderid column in ofmessagearchive  table so that i can get records of distinct chats related to a particular order

so now i want to get diffrent chats related to a order